# 'translateChar' must be called on a CHARSXP

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, chinese-locale

I am trying to export data to a csv-file. My dataframe consist mainly of  strings in Chinese.  I work on a Jupyter notebook with a IRkernel on a Win10 computer with Swedish as the default language.

The locale is set to be chinese:

```
ys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'chs')
```

The line for exporting as csv:

```
write.table(TEST, file = "C:/Users/sxuep/Google Drive/Chengtou_ 
Copy/build/output/TEST.csv"
```

The error message I got:

```
Error in write.table(TEST, file = "C:/Users/sxuep/Google Drive/Chengtou_ 
Copy/build/output/TEST.csv", : 'translateChar' must be called on a CHARSXP
Traceback:

1. write.csv(TEST, file = "C:/Users/sxuep/Google Drive/Chengtou_ 
Copy/build/output/TEST.csv")
2. eval.parent(Call)
3. eval(expr, p)
4. eval(expr, p)
5. write.table(TEST, file = "C:/Users/sxuep/Google Drive/Chengtou_ 
Copy/build/output/TEST.csv", 
.     col.names = NA, sep = ",", dec = ".", qmethod = "double")
```

I tried "dput(head(test)) " and I got garbled text output:

```
structure(list(Ö¤È¯´úÂë = c("122402.SH", "101454021.IB", "101558031.IB", 
"122217.SH", "101474004.IB", "101575002.IB"), Ö¤È¯¼ò³Æ = c("15³Ç½¨01", 
"14Éî¸ßËÙMTN001", "15Éî¸ßËÙMTN001", "12ÓåË®Îñ", "14»¦³Ç¿ØMTN001", 
"15»¦³Ç¿ØMTN001(3ÄêÆÚ)"), ·¢ÐÐ¶î = c("58", "10", "9", "15", "20", 
"15"), Õ®È¯Óà¶î = c("58", "10", "9", "15", "20", "15"), ÆðÏ¢ÈÕÆÚ = c("2015-
07-20", 
"2014-05-08", "2015-08-18", "2013-01-29", "2014-04-22", "2015-04-23"
), µ½ÆÚÈÕÆÚ = c("2022-07-20", "2017-05-08", "2018-08-18", "2018-01-29", 
"2019-04-22", "2018-04-23"), Õ®È¯ÆÚÏÞ = c("7", "3", "3", "5", 
"5", "3"), Æ±ÃæÀûÂÊ = c("4.4", "5.5", "3.95", "5.12", "6.28", 
"4.59"), ÀûÂÊËµÃ÷ = c("20150720-20200719,Æ±ÃæÀûÂÊ:4.40%;20200720-
20220719,Æ±ÃæÀûÂÊ:4.40%+ÉÏµ÷»ùµã", 
"5.5%", "3.95%", "5.12%", "6.28%", "4.59%"), ½»Ò×Æ½Ì¨ = 
c("¾º¼Û+¹Ì¶¨ÊÕÒæÆ½Ì¨", 
NA, NA, "¾º¼Û+¹Ì¶¨ÊÕÒæÆ½Ì¨", NA, NA), Ê¡·Ý = c("±±¾©", "¹ã¶«Ê¡", 
"¹ã¶«Ê¡", "ÖØÇì", "ÉÏº£", "ÉÏº£"), WindÐÐÒµÃû³Æ = c("·¿µØ²ú", 
"¹¤Òµ", "¹¤Òµ", "¹«ÓÃÊÂÒµ", "·¿µØ²ú", "·¿µØ²ú"), Ô±¹¤×ÜÊý = c("2613", 
"5254", "5254", "5188", "2144", "2144"), ×¢²á×Ê±¾ = c("156704", 
"218077.0326", "218077.0326", "480000", "252957.5634", "252957.5634"
), ÌØÊâÌõ¿î = c("»ØÊÛ,µ÷ÕûÆ±ÃæÀûÂÊ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ÌØÊâÌõ¿îÎÄ×Ö = 
    c("»ØÊÛ:·¢ÐÐÈË·¢³ö¹ØÓÚÊÇ·ñÉÏµ÷±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯Æ±ÃæÀûÂÊ¼°ÉÏµ÷·ù¶ÈµÄ¹«¸æºó,Í¶×ÊÕßÓÐÈ¨Ñ¡ÔñÔ
 Ú±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯µÚ5¸ö¼ÆÏ¢Äê¶ÈµÄÍ¶×ÊÕß»ØÊÛµÇ¼ÇÆÚÄÚ½øÐÐµÇ¼Ç,½«Æä³ÖÓÐµÄ±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯È«²¿»ò²¿·Ö°´ÃæÖµ»ØÊÛ¸ø·¢ÐÐÈË.±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯µÚ5¸ö¼ÆÏ¢Äê¶È¸¶Ï¢ÈÕ¼´Îª»ØÊÛÖ§¸¶ÈÕ,·¢ÐÐÈË½«°´ÕÕÉÏº£Ö¤È¯½»Ò×ËùºÍÕ®È¯µÇ¼Ç»ú¹¹Ïà¹ØÒµÎñ¹æÔòÍê³É»ØÊÛÖ§¸¶¹¤×÷.Í¶×ÊÕßÄâÐÐÊ¹²¿·Ö»òÈ«²¿»ØÊÛÑ¡ÔñÈ¨,ÐëÓÚ¹«Ë¾·¢³ö¹ØÓÚÊÇ·ñÉÏµ÷±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯Æ±ÃæÀûÂÊÒÔ¼°ÉÏµ÷·ù¶ÈµÄ¹«¸æÖ®ÈÕÆð5¸ö½»Ò×ÈÕÄÚ½øÐÐµÇ¼Ç,ÏàÓ¦µÄ¹«Ë¾Õ®È¯Æ±Ãæ×Ü¶î½«±»¶³½á½»Ò×;ÈôÍ¶×ÊÕßÎ´×öµÇ¼Ç,ÔòÊÓÎª·ÅÆú»ØÊÛÑ¡ÔñÈ¨,¼ÌÐø³ÖÓÐ±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯.£»µ÷ÕûÆ±ÃæÀûÂÊ:·¢ÐÐÈËÓÐÈ¨¾ö¶¨ÊÇ·ñÔÚ±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯´æÐøÆÚµÄµÚ5ÄêÄ©ÉÏµ÷±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯ºó2ÄêµÄÆ±ÃæÀûÂÊ.·¢ÐÐÈË½«ÓÚ±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯µÚ5¸ö¼ÆÏ¢Äê¶È¸¶Ï¢ÈÕÇ°µÄµÚ20¸ö½»Ò×ÈÕ,ÔÚÖÐ¹úÖ¤¼à»áÖ¸¶¨µÄÐÅÏ¢ÅûÂ¶Ã½ÌåÉÏ·¢²¼¹ØÓÚÊÇ·ñÉÏµ÷±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯Æ±ÃæÀûÂÊÒÔ¼°ÉÏµ÷·ù¶ÈµÄ¹«¸æ.Èô·¢ÐÐÈËÎ´ÐÐÊ¹ÀûÂÊÉÏµ÷È¨,Ôò±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯ºóÐøÆÚÏÞÆ±ÃæÀûÂÊÈÔÎ¬³ÖÔ­ÓÐÆ±ÃæÀûÂÊ²»±ä.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Ö¤È¯È«³Æ = c("±±¾©³Ç½¨Í¶×Ê·¢Õ¹¹É·ÝÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾2015Äê¹«Ë¾Õ®È¯(µÚÒ»ÆÚ)", 
NA, "ÉîÛÚ¸ßËÙ¹«Â·¹É·ÝÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾2015Äê¶ÈµÚÒ»ÆÚÖÐÆÚÆ±¾Ý", "ÖØÇìË®Îñ¼¯ÍÅ¹É·ÝÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾2012Äê¹«Ë¾Õ®È¯", 
"ÉÏº£³ÇÍ¶¿Ø¹É¹É·ÝÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾2014Äê¶ÈµÚÒ»ÆÚÖÐÆÚÆ±¾Ý", "ÉÏº£³ÇÍ¶¿Ø¹É¹É·ÝÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾2015Äê¶ÈµÚÒ»ÆÚÖÐÆÚÆ±¾Ý(Æ·ÖÖÒ»)"
), ×Ê½ðÓÃÍ¾ = c("¹«Ë¾ÄâÊ¹ÓÃ±¾´ÎÄ¼¼¯×Ê½ðÖÐ28.15ÒÚÔª³¥»¹¹«Ë¾Õ®Îñ,ÒÔ½µµÍ²ÆÎñ·ÑÓÃ²¢ÓÅ»¯Õ®Îñ½á¹¹.±¾´Î¹«¿ª·¢ÐÐ¹«Ë¾Õ®È¯Ä¼¼¯×Ê½ðµ½Î»Ö®Ç°,·¢ÐÐÈË½«¸ù¾Ý¹«Ë¾Õ®ÎñµÄÊµ¼ÊÇé¿öÒÔ×Ô³ï×Ê½ðÏÈÐÐ³¥»¹,²¢ÔÚÄ¼¼¯×Ê½ðµ½Î»Ö®ºóÓèÒÔÖÃ»».±¾´ÎÄâ³¥»¹µÄ¹«Ë¾Õ®ÎñÃ÷Ï¸ÈçÏÂ:\r\n´û¿îµ¥Î»\tÄâ³¥»¹½ð¶î(ÒÚÔª)\r\nÎå¿ó¹ú¼ÊÐÅÍÐÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾\t8\r\nÖÐ¹ú½ð¹È¹ú¼ÊÐÅÍÐÓÐÏÞÔðÈÎ¹«Ë¾\t6\r\n½¨ÐÅÐÅÍÐÓÐÏÞÔðÈÎ¹«Ë¾\t4.5\r\nÐÂÊ±´úÐÅÍÐ¹É·ÝÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾\t6.40\r\nÐÂ»ªÐÅÍÐ¹É·ÝÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾\t2.80\r\nÎ÷²ØÐÅÍÐÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾\t0.45\r\n¹«Ë¾ÄâÊ¹ÓÃ±¾´ÎÄ¼¼¯×Ê½ðÖÐ29.85ÒÚÔªÓÃÓÚ²¹³äÁ÷¶¯×Ê½ð,Âú×ã¹«Ë¾ÔËÓªÐèÇó.", 
NA, "¹«Ë¾±¾´Î·¢ÐÐÖÐÆÚÆ±¾ÝÄ¼¼¯×Ê½ð9ÒÚÔªÖ÷ÒªÓÃÍ¾Îª³¥»¹ÒøÐÐ½è¿î¼°²¹³ä¼¯ÍÅÓªÔË×Ê½ð,ÆäÖÐ8ÒÚÔªÓÃÓÚ³¥»¹±¾¹«Ë¾¼°¿Ø¹É×Ó¹«Ë¾ÒøÐÐ½è¿î,1ÒÚÔªÓÃÓÚ²¹³ä±¾¹«Ë¾ÓªÔË×Ê½ð.", 
"±¾ÆÚÕ®È¯µÄÄ¼¼¯×Ê½ð¿Û³ý·¢ÐÐ·ÑÓÃºó,È«²¿ÓÃÓÚ²¹³ä¹«Ë¾µÄÓªÔË×Ê½ð,ÉÏÊö°²ÅÅ¾ßÓÐ±ØÒªÐÔºÍºÏÀíÐÔ.·¢ÐÐÈË×÷ÎªË®ÎñÐÐÒµÖÐµÄ´óÐÍÆóÒµ,¾ßÓÐÒ»´ÎÐÔÍ¶×Ê¹æÄ£´ó,Í¶×Ê»ØÊÕÖÜÆÚ³¤µÄÌØµã.Ë®ÎñÐÐÒµ×÷ÎªµØÇøµÄ»ù´¡ÉèÊ©,Æä½¨Éè¹æÄ£Ó¦Âú×ã¸ÃµØÇøÒ»¶¨Ê±ÆÚµÄÐèÒª,ÊÊ¶È³¬Ç°½¨Éè.¼øÓÚË®ÎñÐÐÒµÊôÓÚ×Ê±¾ÃÜ¼¯ÐÍÐÐÒµ,¹«Ë¾×Ê±¾ÐÔÖ§³ö½Ï´ó,ÆäÖÐÒÔ¹Ì¶¨×Ê²úÍ¶×ÊÎªÖ÷,Ö÷ÒªÓÃÓÚÀ©½¨»òÐÂ½¨´óÐÍ¹©Ë®,ÎÛË®´¦Àí³§¼°ÅäÌ×ÉèÊ©,ÒÔ¼°¼¼Êõ¸ÄÔì,½¨Öþ¹¤³ÌµÈ,ÍùÍùÐèÒªÊýÒÔÒÚ¼ÆµÄ×Ê½ðÍ¶Èë.¹«Ë¾½üÄêÀ´²»¶Ï¼Ó´óÁËÒÔ×ÔÀ´Ë®¹©Ó¦ºÍÎÛË®´¦ÀíÎªºËÐÄÒµÎñÁìÓòµÄÍ¶×Ê½¨Éè,ÈÕ³£ÓªÔË×Ê½ðÐèÇóÁ¿²»¶ÏÔö¼Ó.ÔÚ×¥ºÃÉÏÊöÏîÄ¿½¨ÉèµÄÍ¬Ê±,±¾¹«Ë¾Ò²½«Ñ°ÇóÍ¨¹ýÊÕ¹º¼æ²¢²ßÂÔ²»¶ÏÀ©´óÒµÎñ¹æÄ£,Ìá¸ßÊÐ³¡Õ¼ÓÐÂÊ.Òò´Ë²¹³äÓªÔË×Ê½ðÊÇÊ®·Ö±ØÒªµÄ,½«ÏÔÖøÌáÉý¹«Ë¾µÄ¿¹·çÏÕÄÜÁ¦,ÓÅ»¯²ÆÎñ½á¹¹,Ö§³Ö¹«Ë¾µÄ³¤ÆÚ·¢Õ¹.", 
"·¢ÐÐÈË±¾´ÎÖÐÆÚÆ±¾Ý×¢²á¶î¶È20ÒÚÔª,½«Ò»´ÎÐÔ·¢ÐÐÍê±Ï,Ä¼¼¯×Ê½ðÈ«²¿ÓÃÓÚ³¥»¹¹«Ë¾±¾²¿µÄ¶ÌÆÚÒøÐÐ½è¿î,ÓÅ»¯¹«Ë¾Õ®Îñ½á¹¹.", 
"±¾´ÎÄ¼¼¯×Ê½ð¼Æ»®³¥»¹¹«Ë¾±¾²¿µÄÒøÐÐ½è¿î."), Ö¤¼à»áÐÐÒµ·ÖÀà = c("·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ", 
NA, "½»Í¨ÔËÊä¡¢²Ö´¢ºÍÓÊÕþÒµ-ÌúÂ·ÔËÊäÒµ-ÌúÂ·ÔËÊäÒµ-ÌúÂ·ÔËÊäÒµ", 
"µçÁ¦¡¢ÈÈÁ¦¡¢È¼Æø¼°Ë®Éú²úºÍ¹©Ó¦Òµ-Ë®µÄÉú²úºÍ¹©Ó¦Òµ-Ë®µÄÉú²úºÍ¹©Ó¦Òµ-Ë®µÄÉú²úºÍ¹©Ó¦Òµ", 
"·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ", "·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ-·¿µØ²úÒµ"
), windÐÐÒµ·ÖÀà = c("·¿µØ²ú--·¿µØ²ú¢ò--·¿µØ²ú¹ÜÀíºÍ¿ª·¢--·¿µØ²ú¿ª·¢", 
NA, "¹¤Òµ--ÔËÊä--½»Í¨»ù´¡ÉèÊ©--¹«Â·ÓëÌúÂ·", "¹«ÓÃÊÂÒµ--¹«ÓÃÊÂÒµ¢ò--Ë®Îñ¢ó--Ë®Îñ", 
"·¿µØ²ú--·¿µØ²ú¢ò--·¿µØ²ú¹ÜÀíºÍ¿ª·¢--·¿µØ²ú¿ª·¢", "·¿µØ²ú--·¿µØ²ú¢ò--·¿µØ²ú¹ÜÀíºÍ¿ª·¢--·¿µØ²ú¿ª·¢"
), ÉêÍòÐÐÒµ·ÖÀà = c("·¿µØ²ú--·¿µØ²ú¿ª·¢", NA, "½»Í¨ÔËÊä--¸ßËÙ¹«Â·", 
"¹«ÓÃÊÂÒµ--Ë®Îñ", "·¿µØ²ú--·¿µØ²ú¿ª·¢", "·¿µØ²ú--·¿µØ²ú¿ª·¢"), 
    ·¢ÐÐ»ú¹¹ = c("SH", "IB", "IB", "SH", "IB", "IB"), Õ®È¯ÀàÐÍ = c(NA, 
    "MTN", "MTN", NA, "MTN", "MTN"), Ö¤¼à»áÐÐÒµ = c("·¿µØ²úÒµ", 
    "NA", "ÌúÂ·", "¹©Ó¦", "·¿µØ²úÒµ", "·¿µØ²úÒµ"), windÐÐÒµ = c("·¿µØ²ú", 
    "NA", "¹¤Òµ", "¹«ÓÃÊÂÒµ", "·¿µØ²ú", "·¿µØ²ú"), ÉêÍòÐÐÒµ = c("·¿µØ²ú", 
    "NA", "¸ßËÙ¹«Â·", "¹«ÓÃÊÂÒµ", "·¿µØ²ú", "·¿µØ²ú")), .Names = c("Ö¤È¯´úÂë", 
"Ö¤È¯¼ò³Æ", "·¢ÐÐ¶î", "Õ®È¯Óà¶î", "ÆðÏ¢ÈÕÆÚ", "µ½ÆÚÈÕÆÚ", "Õ®È¯ÆÚÏÞ", 
"Æ±ÃæÀûÂÊ", "ÀûÂÊËµÃ÷", "½»Ò×Æ½Ì¨", "Ê¡·Ý", "WindÐÐÒµÃû³Æ", "Ô±¹¤×ÜÊý", 
"×¢²á×Ê±¾", "ÌØÊâÌõ¿î", "ÌØÊâÌõ¿îÎÄ×Ö", "Ö¤È¯È«³Æ", "×Ê½ðÓÃÍ¾", 
"Ö¤¼à»áÐÐÒµ·ÖÀà", "windÐÐÒµ·ÖÀà", "ÉêÍòÐÐÒµ·ÖÀà", "·¢ÐÐ»ú¹¹", 
"Õ®È¯ÀàÐÍ", "Ö¤¼à»áÐÐÒµ", "windÐÐÒµ", "ÉêÍòÐÐÒµ"), row.names = c(NA, 

-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My session information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] wordcloud_2.5      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 jiebaR_0.9.1       jiebaRD_0.1       
 [5] bindrcpp_0.2       haven_1.1.0        readxl_1.0.0       stringr_1.2.0     
 [9] dplyr_0.7.2        ggplot2_2.2.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12        compiler_3.4.1      cellranger_1.1.0   
 [4] plyr_1.8.4          bindr_0.1           forcats_0.2.0      
 [7] tools_3.4.1         digest_0.6.12       uuid_0.1-2         
[10] jsonlite_1.5        evaluate_0.10.1     tibble_1.3.4       
[13] gtable_0.2.0        pkgconfig_2.0.1     rlang_0.1.2        
[16] IRdisplay_0.4.4     IRkernel_0.8.8.9000 repr_0.12.0        
[19] grid_3.4.1          glue_1.1.1          R6_2.2.2           
[22] pbdZMQ_0.2-6        magrittr_1.5        scales_0.5.0       
[25] assertthat_0.2.0    colorspace_1.3-2    labeling_0.3       
[28] stringi_1.1.5       lazyeval_0.2.0      munsell_0.4.3      
[31] slam_0.1-40         crayon_1.3.2
```

I don't understand the error message.

Comment: How did you import the data into R? Was it imported with the correct encoding?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure. The data was imported as follows:bond_name_purpose <- read_excel("bond_name_purpose.xlsx", col_types = c("text", "text", "text", "text"))  %>%
    tbl_df()

Comment: The importing seemed to be fine. use "head()" all the variables 
 and their values can be printed out correctly.

Comment: This might be a bug in R. Can you figure out what lines in `TEST` are causing the error? Try to find the smallest range `lo:hi` such that `TEST[lo:hi,]` triggers the error, then report `dput` for that range so that we can help debug the problem further.